# Conditions for unique solution of a maximization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $d:=(d_1,d_2) \in S$, and $s:=(s_1,s_2)$ a generic point of $S$. Assume that there exists $s \in S$ such that $s_1>d_1$ and $s_2 >d_2$. Consider the following maximization problem
$$
\begin{align*}
\max_{(s_1,s_2)\in S} & (s_1-d_1)(s_2-d_2)\\
\text{s.t.}\quad & s_1\geq d_1 \text{ and }s_2\geq d_2
\end{align*}$$

Does the problem have a unique solution under certain conditions? In positive case, one of the necessary conditions is $S$ compact and convex?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you list which constraints on $d$ and $S$ I need?

Comment: Does it mean that you are solving the optimization problem over $S\cap \Bbb R^2_{\geq d}$? Can we assume that you choose $d$ such that the latter set is non-empty (i.e. there is at least one feasible point), for example $d$ lies in the interior of $S$?

Comment: @Ilya Oh, the s.t. is way out of place. Editing it.

Comment: @Ilya "Does it mean that you are solving the optimization problem over ...?" Yes." Can we assume that you choose d such that the latter set is non-empty...?" Yes, let's assume that there exists s s.t. s_1>d_1 and s_2 > d_2.

Comment: @AlexR: it just has to deal with the level sets of the objective function. Also, the OP asked whether compactness and convexity are necessary (not sufficient).

Comment: Consider $S = A \cup \{(1,1)\}$ where $A$ is something nasty lying in the negative quadrant, put $d = (1,1)$. Then solution is unique, but compactness and convexity do not hold - so they are not necessary

Comment: @Ilya are compactness and convexity sufficient for uniqueness?

Comment: This is not a convex optimization problem as stated, although it is quasiconvex. To make it fully convex, just take the square root of the objective: $\sqrt{(s_1-d_1)(s_2-d_2)}$. This should allow you to bring to bear the full machinery of convex optimization theory to the problem. I agree with Ilya that it's easiest to just focus on the $d_1=d_2=0$ case, since you can just translate $S$ if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's enough to focus on $d$ being the origin as the original problem can be restated at origin using translation. So, we are given a subset $S$ of the positive quadrant, and we would like to maximize $s_1\cdot s_2$. Think of the level sets of $f(s) = s_1\cdot s_2$: if we have two points lying on the same level set, then by taking the straight line between them we can find the point lying on higher-level sets. Thus, this gives us the intuition that convexity implies uniqueness. Can you proceed from here? At the same time, it's not yet a formal statement, so please be careful - perhaps while trying to show that you'll come up with a counterexample.

I think compactness is irrelevant for uniqueness, and is more about the existence.

---

Regarding uniqueness, suppose that $S$ is just convex and that there exist $s'\neq s''\in S$ such that $f(s') = f(s'') = f^* = \sup_{s\in S}f(s)$. Consider $\hat s = \frac12(s'+s'')\in S$; it satisfies
\begin{align}
  f(\hat s) &= \frac14(s'_1+s'_2)(s''_1+s''_2) = \frac12f^* +\frac14(s'_1s''_2+s''_1s'_2)
\\
&= \frac12f^* + \frac14f^*\left(\frac{s'_1}{s''_1} + \frac{s''_1}{s'_1}\right) > f^*
\end{align}
since $s'_1 \neq s''_1$: recall that for $x>0$ we have $x+\frac1x>2$ unless $x = 1$. Hence, there exists $\hat s\in S$  at which $f$ is greater than $f^*$, contradiction. Thus, if $S$ is convex and there exists a point of maximum, such point is unique.

Comment: Thanks, but for existence isn't enough that there exists s∈S such that s1>d1 and s2>d2?

Comment: @Cris: the maximum may be attained on the boundary, right?

Comment: Yes, it can be attained on the boundary.

Comment: @Cris: in that case, compactness assures that if the solution is attained on the boundary, it belongs to $S$.

Comment: @Cris: see my edit